# How to reduce in CUDA if __syncthreads can't be called inside conditional branches?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, synchronization, reduce

The reduction method [suggested by NVIDIA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) uses `__syncthreads()` inside conditional branching e.g.:

```
if (blockSize >= 512) { if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
```

or

```
for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>32; s>>=1)
{
    if (tid < s)
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    __syncthreads();
}
```

In the second example `__syncthreads()` is inside `for` loop body, which is also a conditional branch.

However, a number of questions on SO raise the problem of `__syncthreads()` inside conditional branches (e.g. [Can I use __syncthreads() after having dropped threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666382/can-i-use-syncthreads-after-having-dropped-threads) and [conditional syncthreads & deadlock (or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146886/conditional-syncthreads-deadlock-or-not) ), and the answers say that `__syncthreads()` in conditional branches may lead to a deadlock. Consequently, reduction method suggested by NVIDIA may deadlock (if believing the documentation on which the answers are based).

Furthermore, if `_syncthreads()` can't be used inside conditional branches, then I'm afraid that many of the basic operations are blocked and reduction is just an example.

So how to do reduction in CUDA without using `__syncthreads()` in conditional branches? Or is it a bug in the documentation?

Comment: Note that in the first code snippet, Blcoksize is a compile time constant or template parameter, so there is no branch emitted by the compiler. Note that in the second the loop trip count is constant for every thread in the block, so again, there is no conditional branching around a `__syncthreads` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limitation is not

> `__syncthreads` cannot be used in conditional branches

The limitation is

> `__syncthreads` cannot be used in branches which will not be traversed by all threads at the same time

Notice that in *both* the examples you give, `__syncthreads` is not covered by a condition that would depend on the thread ID (or some per-thread data). In the first case, `blockSize` is a template parameter which does not depend on thread ID. In the second case, it's likewise after the `if`.

Yes, the for loop's `s > 32` is a condition, but it is a condition whose truth value does not depend on the thread or its data in any way. `blockdim.x` is the same for all threads. And all threads will execute exactly the same modifications of `s`. Which means that *all* threads will reach the `__syncthreads` in exactly the same point of their control flow. Which is perfectly OK.

The other case, where you *cannot* use `__syncthreads`, is a condition which can be true for some threads and false for other ones. In such case, you have to close all conditions to use `__syncthreads`. So instead of this:

```
if (threadIdx.x < SOME_CONSTANT)
{
  operation1();
  __syncthreads();
  operation2();
}
```

You must do this:

```
if (threadIdx.x < SOME_CONSTANT)
{
  operation1();
}
__syncthreads();
if (threadIdx.x < SOME_CONSTANT)
{
  operation2();
}
```

Both of the examples you gave demonstrate this too: the thread-ID-dependent condition is closed before `__syncthreads` is called.

Comment: What about this example? `if ((idx < ds) && (idy < ds)){ ... __syncthreads();}` from https://github.com/olcf/cuda-training-series/blob/9cd77d539d85ee3457e09a083ba299b787b7a16e/exercises/hw2/matrix_mul_shared_solution.cu#L35

Comment: @EduardoReis 8192 (= `ds`) is divisible by 32 (= `blockDim`), so that conditional will never fail. I don't know if the code would still work if that wasn't the case.

Comment: I know that in my kernel code I have something similar `if (idx>=ds) return` whereas the cases the thread does not return, it executes a `__synchthreads();`; and `ds` is not a multiple of `32`. Apparently it works and I don't have deadlocks.

Comment: Just noticed that this matter is further discussed [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/a-stupid-question-on-syncthread-function/64454/2).

Comment: @EduardoReis To summarise the external discussion: If `__syncthreads();` is skipped by some threads, it *may* hang. The code is incorrect, but not guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Does that make the code provided in all tiled-matrix multiplication examples out there, such as the [one provided by NVIDIA folks](https://github.com/olcf/cuda-training-series/blob/9cd77d539d85ee3457e09a083ba299b787b7a16e/exercises/hw2/matrix_mul_shared_solution.cu#L35), incorrect? Asserting that feels wrong.

Comment: For matrices with size that is not multiple of `32`, some threads within the same warp would skip `__synchthreads()`, according the my understanding of the theory presented here.

Comment: @EduardoReis I've reached the limit of my understanding as it was built up from reading CUDA documentation and other materials (such as the discussion you linked to). If you need further clarification, you might post a dedicated question, or perhaps reach out to the author of the OLCF code you're linking to.

Comment: thank you so much for your time taking a look at this and your recommendation. I will do that. As of now, I am writing my trying to avoid having threads not failing on the `__syncthreads()`, such as shown in [here](https://gist.github.com/dniku/f168582fe98ba97346e4).